# How to read characteristics data

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am using BLE device with respect to Xamarin.Forms. Can you please help to resolve the below issue? I am using this [Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.BLE)

### Steps to reproduce

1. After scanning I have some set of devices . I am selecting the device. After selecting, i am connecting to that device.
2. I got some list of services. so i am iterating one service  and i got that service characteristics
3. I got some list of characteristics. I am iterating first characteristics and reading. Application crashed.

### Expected behavior

Tell us what should happen

### Actual behavior

Instead of crash, it should read and give bytes

#### Crashlog

`Excepotion` is not thrown. These are the details i got in output screen

```
12-20 17:54:18.170 D/BluetoothGatt(20372): onConnectionUpdated() - Device=98:07:2D:45:76:83 interval=39 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
12-20 17:54:22.020 D/BluetoothGatt(20372): onConnectionUpdated() - Device=98:07:2D:45:76:83 interval=798 latency=0 timeout=1000 status=0
12-20 17:54:22.290 I/Choreographer(20372): Skipped 248 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-20 17:54:22.292 W/Looper  (20372): Slow Frame: doFrame is 4148ms late
12-20 17:54:24.763 F/        (20372): * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4931, condition `is_ok (error)' not met, function:get_this_async_id, Could not execute the method because the containing type is not fully instantiated. assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
```

### Configuration

**Version of the Plugin:** e.g. 2.1.1 (Latest)

**Platform:** Android  8.1 API - 27

**Device:** Redmi Note

**Xamarin.Forms:** 4.4.0.991265(Latest)

I couldn't attach sample. Here are my snippets

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var services = await _connectedDevice.GetServicesAsync();
            if (services != null)
            {
                var characteristics = await services[0].GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                if (characteristics != null)
                {
                    foreach (var character in characteristics)
                   {
                                var byteValue = await character.ReadAsync(); /// Crashed while reading this line
                                 var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteValue);
                                 output.Text = str;
                            }                  
                }
            }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to change your log level to "Diagnostics" and really try to get more information from before the crash. The first is not a crash, so you can figure this out. Perhaps you can also use a profiler. Also, try to invoke this line on main thread:                                 `var byteValue = await character.ReadAsync();`

Comment: i have invoked in main thread also. the same crash. it couldn't read it. 12-21 11:29:28.585 F/        (32560): * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4931, condition `is_ok (error)' not met, function:get_this_async_id, Could not execute the method because the containing type is not fully instantiated. assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
12-21 11:29:28.586 F/libc    (32560): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 32560 (e.Bluetoothdemo), pid 32560 (e.Bluetoothdemo)

Comment: Resolved pending breakpoint at 'Characteristic.cs:47,1' to void Plugin.BLE.Android.Characteristic.<ReadNativeAsync>d__17.MoveNext () [0x00011].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'Characteristic.cs:54,1' to void Plugin.BLE.Android.Characteristic.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<ReadNativeAsync>b__6 (object sender, Plugin.BLE.Android.CallbackEventArgs.CharacteristicReadCallbackEventArgs args) [0x00023].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'Characteristic.cs:61,1' to void Plugin.BLE.Android.Characteristic.<>c__DisplayClass17_1.<ReadNativeAsync>b__7 (object sender, System.EventArgs args) [0x00001].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i read the characteristics through ViewModel it is working good. Instead of button click , i created a set of services in listview and on item tapped , i am listing out set of characteristics and then i am reading